# Sum of 2 two's complement binary number

Tags: math, binary, addition, twos-complement

I am familiar with two's complement when performing addition in 4 bits, then I am confused when I face the question below

** Find the sum of the 2 two's complement binary number 010111 and 110101 in 8 bit output**

Below is my attempt, but I am in a dilemma, should I

(1) discard the carry, then add two 0, so the answer is 00001100,  which is 12 in decimal
[image]

Thank you !

(2) just add 1 in the beginning, so it the answer is 11001100, which is 204 in decimal

[image]

Comment: At the end I make it 00010111 + 11110101 = 00001100, I think it might me correct

Comment: What is `23 + 53` in decimal?

Comment: @beaker should be 23 + (-9) = 12, those are represented in two's complement

Comment: Okay, that's the big question. It says 8-bit output, but are the original numbers 8-bit, or 6-bit? Is the second number 12 or 53? It looks to me like the second number should be `00110101`, but I'm not the one who can clarify that for you.

Comment: The original numbers are 6 bits, should have mentioned that, sorry

Comment: Okay, so your numbers are `23` and `-11`. `23 + -11 = 12`.

Answer (score 0):

For the Twos Complement in 8 bit you have to invert ALL 8 bits of the number

As far as I know the ones complement and twos complement operate on the absolute value so:

The Binary Number 010111 is represented in 8 bits with 00010111

```
C_1(00010111) = 00010111 xor 11111111 = 11101000

C_2(00010111) = C_1 + 1 = 00010111 + 1 = 00011000
```

The Binary Number 110101 is represented in 8 bits -> 00110101

```
C_1(00110101) = 00110101 xor 11111111 = 11001010

C_2(00010111) = C_1 + 1 = 11001010 + 1 = 11001011
```

Now add the two twos-complements:

```
C_2(00010111) + C_2(00010111) = 00011000 + 11001011 = 11100011
```

Pls correct me if messed something up with sign bits (I just took the binary numbers as is in 8 bit)...

Comment: If your numbers are signed you have to ignore the first bit and do the 2s complement of the remaining 5 in 8 representation.